# Sending a json object in a post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, serialization, json.net

I am trying to create a virtual machine through a post method but I have not been able to create it since I cannot send the json file correctly.

This is my code:

```
// Create a json object
var deploy = new Deploy
{
    name = "RandomName",                                
    folder = "folder_3044",
    resource_pool = "resgroup-4035"
};  

//Change it into a json file  
var deployResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deploy);

//Change this file into a string so we can send it to the post method
var jsonContent = new StringContent(deployResult);

//Make post and send the needed information
var postResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("URI", jsonContent);
return (content);
```

---

When executing my code in Postman it gives me a false positive because it sends something but it seems that it does not send the json as I wanted but the code below:

```json
{
    "headers": [
        {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": [
                "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "Content-Length",
            "value": [
                "97"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Can anyone help me with this? I just need to send that json in my post like I do when sending from Postman.
Ps: I use .Net core and I can't change even if I want to.
This is the json that should be sent for it to work:

```json
{
    "name": "RandomName",
    "placement": {
        "folder": "folder_3044",
        "resource_pool": "resgroup-4035"
    }
}
```

Comment: `return (content);` shouldn't you return postResponse.Result?

Comment: Whenever you create a `StringContent` you have to specify the Content-Type, like this: `new StringContent(deployResult, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")`

Comment: Depending on the .NET version which you are using, it might support [`PostAsJsonAsync`](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/sending-and-receiving-json-using-httpclient-with-system-net-http-json)

Comment: You have to show Deploy class and API code.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to [@Peter Csala's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71492620/sending-a-json-object-in-a-post-method/71518539#comment126363178_71492620): When I specified the content-type as you advised, it worked. Just for future references, we need these two lines of code. (Don't forget to include the assembly `System.Text` on top.)

```
using System.Text;

new StringContent(deployResult, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```